# HTML based brochures/flyers

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am wondering if its possible to be able to create an html type brochure that can get printed or saved to pdf but the html template would have a few things that the user can alter such as adding there own images putting there details in and a description of sorts.

I would prefer to use javascript,html,css and if necessary php.

I am at the moment kind of stuck at the moment I have created an html form so it does not go further than that.

Is there an api of sorts that I can use to create several templates and allow the users to be able add what they need.

Here is the form so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="FlyCreator.aspx.vb" Inherits="FlyCreator" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Flyer Creator test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainFlyer.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

<div id="form_container">

<h1><a>Untitled Form</a></h1>
<form id="form_Flyer" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<div class="form_description">
<%--<h2>Flyer Creator Test</h2>--%>
</div>
<ul >
     <li class="section_break">
        <h3>Name and Title:</h3>
         <p>Leave fields blank if they are not needed</p>
    </li> 

<li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
     <span>
         <input id="element_1_1" name= "element_1_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>
         <label>First</label>
    </span>
     <span>
        <input id="element_1_2" name= "element_1_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
    </span> 
    <span>

    <input id="element_1_3" name="element_1_3" class="element text" maxlength="50" size="40" />
       <label>Title</label>
        </span>
</li>
    <li class="section_break">
<h3>Business Address:</h3>
<p></p>
</li>
    <li id="li_3" >
        <div>
            <input id="element_3_1" name="element_3_1" class="element text" maxlength="35" size="30" />
            <label>Company Name</label>
         </div>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3_2" name="element_3_2" class="element text" value="" type="text" maxlength="35" size="30"/>
            <label for="element_3_1">Street Address</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_3_3" name="element_3_3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text"/>
            <label for="element_3_2">City</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input id="element_3_4" name="element_3_3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text"/>
            <label for="element_3_4"> Province / Region</label>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_3_5" name="element_3_5" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text"/>
            <label for="element_3_5">Postal / Zip Code</label>
        </div>
</li>
<li class="section_break">
<h3>Phones,Emails, and Website:</h3>
<p></p>
</li>
    <li id="li_21" >
        <label class="description" for="element_21" style="text-align:left;color:black"><b>phone no1 :</b> </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_21" name="element_21"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Label</option>
            <option value="1" >home</option>
            <option value="2" >office</option>
            <option value="3" >cell</option>
            <option value="4" >fax</option>
        </select>
            <input name="ph11" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph11" size="3"/>
            <input name="ph12" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph12" size="3"/>
            <input name="ph13" value="" maxlength="4" type="text" id="ph13" size="3"/>
</div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_22" >
        <label class="description" for="element_22">phone no2: </label>
        <div>
            <select class="element select medium" id="element_22" name="element_22"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Label</option>
                <option value="1" >home</option>
                <option value="2" >office</option>
                <option value="3" >cell</option>
                <option value="4" >fax</option>
            </select>
                <input name="ph21" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph21" size="3"/>
                <input name="ph22" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph22" size="3"/>
                <input name="ph23" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph23" size="3"/>
        </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_23" >
        <label class="description" for="element_23">phone no3: </label>
            <div>
                <select class="element select medium" id="element_23" name="element_23"> 
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose label</option>
                    <option value="1" >home</option>
                    <option value="2" >office</option>
                    <option value="3" >cell</option>
                    <option value="4" >fax</option>
                </select>
                  <input name="ph31" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph31" size="3"/>
                  <input name="ph32" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph32" size="3"/>
                  <input name="ph33" value="" maxlength="3" type="text" id="ph33" size="3"/>
            </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Email : </label>
            <div>
                 <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
            </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">company or personal website: </label>
            <div>
                 <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="http://"/> 
            </div> 
</li>
    <li class="section_break">
<h3>Section Break</h3>
<p></p>
</li>       <li id="li_8" >
<label class="description" for="element_8">Photo of your self </label>
<div>
<input id="element_8" name="element_8" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>       <li id="li_9" >
<label class="description" for="element_9">Main photo of house </label>
<div>
<input id="element_9" name="element_9" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>       <li id="li_10" >
<label class="description" for="element_10">interior 1 </label>
<div>
<input id="element_10" name="element_10" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>       <li id="li_11" >
<label class="description" for="element_11">house 2 </label>
<div>
<input id="element_11" name="element_11" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>       <li id="li_12" >
<label class="description" for="element_12">house 3 </label>
<div>
<input id="element_12" name="element_12" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>       <li id="li_13" >
<label class="description" for="element_13">company logo </label>
<div>
<input id="element_13" name="element_13" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>
    <li id="li_14" >
<label class="description" for="element_14">qr code </label>
<div>
<input id="element_14" name="element_14" class="element file" type="file"/> 
</div>  
</li>
    <li id ="li_15">
        <label class="description" for="element_15">Opional IEASA logo</label><img src="images/ieasa.gif" />
        <div >
            <input id="element_15a" name="select1" value="on" type="radio" />On<br />
            <input id="element 15b" name="select1" value="on" type="radio" />Off<br />
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="section_break">
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
</li>
    <li id="li_16" >
        <label class="description" for="element_16">Property Information:</label>

<div>
<input id="element_16_1" name="element_16_1" class="element text large" value="" type="text"/>
<label for="element_16_1">Street Address</label>
</div>

<div>
<input id="element_16_2" name="element_16_2" class="element text large" value="" type="text"/>
<label for="element_16_2">Address Line 2</label>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <input id="element_16_3" name="element_16_3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text"/>
    <label for="element_16_3">City</label>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <input id="element_16_4" name="element_16_4" class="element text medium" value="" type="text"/>
    <label for="element_16_4"> Province / Region</label>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <input id="element_16_5" name="element_16_5" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
    <label for="element_16_5">Postal / Zip Code</label>
</div>

</li>
    <li id="li_17" >
        <label class="description" for="element_17">Description of property </label>
            <div>
              <textarea id="element_17" name="element_17" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
            </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_18" >
        <label class="description" for="element_18">property details </label>
            <div>
              <textarea id="element_18" name="element_18" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
            </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_19" >
        <label class="description" for="element_19">property details 2 </label>
            <div>
                <textarea id="element_19" name="element_19" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
            </div> 
</li>
    <li id="li_20" >
        <label class="description" for="element_20">property details 3 </label>
            <div>
              <textarea id="element_20" name="element_20" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
            </div> 
</li>

<li class="buttons">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="745249" />

<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a couple of templates with Photoshop, Then if the user is done and pressed the submit button you can try to send all the information to a temporarily database. When that is send you can retrive the data and put it inside divs that you have placed in youre template. So when the data is recieved from the database, the data will be placed in the divs. You dont have to use databases but maybe this will give you an idea in how you can accomplish your goal, Good Luck

Comment: Im trying to limit the amount of information that goes in the database at the moment as the brochure will have images in too. I am currently using a brocure I created in photoshop but am not a 100% sure how to go about getting the selected info into those sections that was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create and thereafter save/print pdf, you can try "DOMPDF". Its pretty easy to use and good results. Essentially what you would do is create your application and user options as usual using html/css/php etc. Add in your adjustments etc.

Once done, you wrap the result in a php variable called......well for now, called " `$html` ",
then inside of your processing page you put something like

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("YOURPDFNAMEHERE.pdf");
?>
```

and the domPDF lib will create a pdf with your html in it.

check it out
https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

good luck

EDIT*** 
to expand on this, say that your result from all the edits/user selections is html that looks like this:

```
(random code)
<table >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td width="420" style="background-color:#f00; color:#fff;">lopan?</td>
    <td>lopan right</td>
</tr>



</table>
```

then youd assign this code into any php variable. We will call it " $html ". Youd assign it like so:

```
$html = '
<table >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td width="420" style="background-color:#f00; color:#fff;">lopan?</td>
    <td>lopan right</td>
</tr>



</table>
';
```

and this below

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

takes your $html content and creates the pdf accordingly.